# How to copy one folder form host to a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

My machine is a windows 7. I've installed VMWare workstation 10. And on that VMware, the windows 8.1. Now when I want to copy one folder form 7 to that 8.1 (by copy/paste or drag- and-drop) it's impossible (un-allowed).
Is there any way for that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 ways:
- simplest way is to use VMware tools for sharing. For this option, you need in install VMware tools - as suggested by message in you screenshot. There is a menu for this in VM window once your start it.

- an alternative is to create a share in Windows7 side, and connect it as network drive from VM side.

Comment: you can also use a usb stick to exchange the files. Another posibility is using dropbox, google drive etc. to exchange files.

Comment: VMware tools is like a driver for mouse/graphics/file sharing/etc. After installing it you only need to drag and drop the file between the host/guest

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm trying to download the tool. Then I'll aware your of results.

Comment: Does anyone know of the size of this tool (Vmware Tolls) in MB?